# When does the callback function in setState method execute?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

In the following code, the callback of the setState method does not execute, as expected, after the state is set. If you check the console you will see what I mean. The state read in console.log is not the updated one. It's always the previous one (you can check this by clicking on the "Read array" button), but according to the react docs:

> The second parameter to setState() is an optional callback function that **will be executed once setState is completed** and the component is re-rendered. Generally we recommend using componentDidUpdate() for such logic instead.

While I understand the recommendation is to use componentDidUpdate, I'm curious as to why it doesn't work as expected or if I'm reading the documentation wrong. By "once the setState is completed" I understand that it's executed once the new state has been saved.

```js
class StateAsync extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        items: [
        { text: "JavaScript" },
        { text: "React" },
        { text: "JSFiddle" },
        { text: "Awesome" }
      ],
      selectedItems: []
    }
    
    
    this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this);
    this.test = this.test.bind(this);
  }
  
  handleSelect(e) {

        let selectedId = this.state.items[e.target.id].text;
        let clone = [...this.state.selectedItems];
        
        if(e.target.checked == false) {
          
            console.log("Removing item.");
            clone = clone.filter(item => item !== selectedId);
            this.setState({
                selectedItems: clone
            }, console.log("Remove callback result is: " + this.state.selectedItems)); //-- the callback does not execute AFTER the state is set
                       
        }else{
        
            this.setState({
                selectedItems: [...this.state.selectedItems, selectedId]
            }, console.log("Add callback result is: " + this.state.selectedItems)); //-- callback gets executed before the state is set
            console.log("Item added.");
        }
        
    }

    test(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        console.log(this.state.selectedItems);
    }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span onClick={this.test} className="d-none d-md-block"><button className="btn btn-dim btn-outline-light">Read Array</button></span>
        <ol>
        {this.state.items.map((item,index) => (
          <li key={index}>
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.handleSelect} id={index}/> 
              <span>{index} - {item.text}</span>
            </label>
          </li>
        ))}
        </ol>
        <span id="readout">
          
        </span>
      </div>
      
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<StateAsync />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.done {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

input {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Here's a codepen as well:

https://codepen.io/nicholas_cb/pen/VweXoVa?editors=0010

So, the question is does the callback in the setState method execute once the setState is completed or at the same time/before?

Comment: You are not passing a callback. You are calling `console.log` immediately and pass its return value (`undefined`) to `setState` as "callback". You have to pass a function instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are executing the console log immediately and passing its return value (which will be `undefined`) as the callback.

This is why you get the current state logged and there is nothing (`undefined` as callback) to be executed later with the updated state.

Instead, you will need to pass a callback function that, in turn, calls the console log:

```
this.setState({
  selectedItems: clone
}, () => console.log("Remove callback result is: " + this.state.selectedItems));
```

Comment: So basically console.log is not a function and so, even though it's the second argument in setState, it is sort of executed async? If you pass a function that calls the log method in the console object then it executes as expected. Have I got this right?

I was initially expecting for the second argument to be executed after the setState is completed regardless of what the second argument is.

Comment: `console.log` is a function but you are invoking it immediately, which is why you get the current state logged. It is then the return value from `console.log()` that actually gets passed as the callback for `setState` to run after updating. `console.log` returns `undefined` so there is nothing to be called later with the updated state.

Comment: @Hantu: If you see `foo(bar())` what do you expect to happen? `bar` will be executed first and its return value is passed to `foo`. That's true no matter what kind of argument `foo` expects. The same applies to your situation: `this.setState(..., console.log(...))`. *Passing* a function and *calling* a function are two different things.

Comment: @Felix your comment finally made me realize my mistake. Indeed passing a reference to a function and calling a function are not the same thing. This is actually the on point correct answer. If you're interested to post it as an answer instead of a comment I'd really like to select it as the correct answer. If not Steve's answer will be selected as it's basically the same answer just not as straightforward/clear maybe. Thank you both by the way, most helpful!

Answer (score 1):

The callback does execute after the state changes.

The problem that you didn't add a callback.

```
setState(updater, [callback])
```

```
this.setState(
  { selectedItems: clone },
  // closure on this.state.selectedItems
  () => console.log("Remove callback result is: " + this.state.selectedItems)
);
```

Comment: No. The problem is that the OP doesn't pass a callback at all.

Comment: Yea you are right didn't notice, but still the answer stands, need to check it

Comment: Accessing `this.state` inside the callback will be fine. `this` doesn't change throughout the element's lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are not passing a callback to the setState() method, instead you are directly passing the console.log() statement.

You need to do it this way:

```
this.setState({
     selectedItems: clone
}, () => {
     console.log("Remove callback result is: " + this.state.selectedItems
}); //-- the callback does not execute AFTER the state is set
```